# Display JSON file in browser with Mule

Tags: java, json, mule

I am using JSON file to show the schema and have give this config:

```
<flow name="api-schema" doc:name="api-schema">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="8080" path="schema" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:static-resource-handler resourceBase="${app.home}/src/main/resources/" defaultFile="schema" doc:name="HTTP Static Resource Handler"/>
</flow>
```

But when I am running it, its always asking to download the file. I have tried in Chrome and Safari both. How can I instruct mule to display content on browser and don't download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the browser determines what to do with a resource is by looking at the [Content-Type](http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Headers/Content-Type) header.  You can set the header by creating an outbound property with the name "Content-Type" and the value "application/json" like so:

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
```

Since the [static-resource-handler](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Static+Resource+Handler) is now deprecated, you could switch to the [parse-template](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Parse+Template+Reference) processor:

```
<parse-template location="#[message.inboundProperties['http.listener.path']]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set "Content-Type" header to "application/json" then response will be in json format.